# Docker PHP/Nginx environment can't handle folder path with backslashes

Tags: php, nginx, path, backslash, docker-for-windows, docker

I'm running a client Symfony3 application on my Docker for windows. My docker-compose is pretty simple : PHP7.1, Nginx, MySQL, and phpMyAdmin.

Everything runs fine, but I got multiple errors when PHP try to access file paths containing both forward slashed and back slashes.

For example the first error I got is : `"Session Storage was not able to create directory "/var/www/symfony\app/../var/sessions/prod""`

It's not a permissions problem, because when I find the PHP part of code calling this file, and replace `\app` with `/app` everything works fine, and the application runs to the next path like that.

I absolutely cannot replace all backslashes in the code, because other developers may work on Windows and put these backslashed for a reason. However, I'm pretty sure I already ran apps with this king of path without any problem.

Any idea about where it could come from ? Php config ? Nginx config ?

Thanks !

Comment: try to read this https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-dockerfiles-and-the-backtick-backslash-backlash/

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to keep your Dockerfiles looking Windows-y, use the backtick to escape, watch out for instructions that don't work with it, and stick to shell form for running commands:

```
# escape=`

FROM microsoft/nanoserver  
COPY template.html c:\template.html  
RUN mkdir c:\inetpub\wwwroot  
RUN powershell `  
     cat c:\template.html `
     > c:\inetpub\wwwroot\index.html
```

@ref: https://blog.sixeyed.com/windows-dockerfiles-and-the-backtick-backslash-backlash/

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error in Laravel. In my case I run some setup commands like `php artisan cache:clear`, `php artisan config:cache` and `php artisan storage:link` in running Docker container and it helps. Some cached files, links has Windows style paths and this command update it to actual Docker filesystem paths.